# PHPUnit 3.6.10 + ZendFramework 1.11.11 + NetBeans 7.1

Tags: zend-framework, phpunit, wamp

When I create a controller with following through Zend_Tool
command:

`create controller NameController`

... netbeans creates a new controller successfully. BUT, it sends a message in the output window:

`PHPUnit is required in order to generate controller test stubs.`

How do I get Netbeans to automatically create a class with phpunit testing? I searched the net and thousands solutions so far not able to solve ...

Important Notes:

- Have already installed the pear
- Already installed phpunit
- Already included 'phpunit' in the include_path
- Has created a file and includes zf.ini too in the include_path
- Options already configured netbeans, where I informed the directory phpunit.bat.

Is it a bug in NetBeans?

See:

[image: http://img545.imageshack.us/img545/262/001hxw.jpg]

[image: http://img855.imageshack.us/img855/8918/002jfy.jpg]

[image: http://img196.imageshack.us/img196/378/003sfu.jpg]

[image: http://img834.imageshack.us/img834/1858/004qc.jpg]

[image: http://img444.imageshack.us/img444/1020/005jx.jpg]

Comment: well I was about to ask the same question :)

Comment: zend Framework 1 isn't compatible with phpUnit 3.6, you'll have to downgrade to 3.5 http://dustyreagan.com/downgrade-phpunit-3-6-to-3-5-15/

Comment: @max4ever ZF 1.11.11 is compatible with phpUnit 3.6.10. I did a test here and it worked.

Comment: not it isn't http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-11828?focusedCommentId=50087&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-50087

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found a solution.**

In *c:/user/you profile user/.zf.ini*, the config file was like this:

`php.include_path = ".C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.8/pear/PHPUnit;C:/Program Files/NetBeans 7.1/php/zend;C:/wamp/apps/ZendFramework/library"
basicloader.classes.0 = "NetBeansCommandsProvider"`

I took the php.include_path, leaving the file as follows:

`basicloader.classes.0 = "NetBeansCommandsProvider"`

Well .. this is crazy and did not understand because it worked well for me.

*NOTE:* Please note that settings should already be set include_path in php.ini in the C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.8 and C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.21\bin

Thanks to all!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's so much a *Neatbeans* issue as it is a `Zend_Tool` (zf.bat) issue.
You are likely working with a project that was built by `Zend_Tool` before phpunit was installed properly. 
In this case the portion or your *.zfproject.xml* does not have the required information to utilize phpunit. 
*Netbeans* does not actually do anything with `Zend_Tool` other then to provide a graphical interface.
I wish I had a quick fix for this problem, but I don't. I have solved this in the past by:

1. Make sure phpunit is properly setup and working in [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/phpunit.html)

Now you have 2 choices:

1. Remake your project directory with `Zend_Tool` and let the *.zfproject.xml* file be generated with a working phpunit.(This works well with new projects)
2. Make a new project with `Zend_Tool`, look at the *.zfproject.xml* with an editor and change the *.zfproject.xml* for your project to include the phpunit info. This method may take a bit of trial and error to get correct.

To be complete here is an excerpt from one of my *.zfproject.xml* files:

```
<testsDirectory>
      <testPHPUnitConfigFile filesystemName="phpunit.xml"/>
      <testPHPUnitBootstrapFile filesystemName="bootstrap.php"/>
      <testApplicationDirectory>
        <testApplicationControllerDirectory>
          <testApplicationControllerFile forControllerName="Index"/>
        </testApplicationControllerDirectory>
      </testApplicationDirectory>
      <testLibraryDirectory/>
    </testsDirectory>
```

I haven't found a way to regenerate the *.zfproject.xml* file to reflect changes to the environment.

I hope someone else has an easier fix...

Comment: @Rockford, thanks for your reply. However, your code in `xml` was complemented on my _zfproject.xml_, because I had set the project properties (see image 4 in in my ask). I followed your procedure, but did not work for me. But now, I managed to generate a PHPUnit test controller with only one thing: **remove the `php.include_path` in `zf.ini`**. What folly!

Comment: I didn't even know the zf.ini existed, thanks for the answer.